# IF statement into another IF statement DW 2.0

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

```
 var lnc_id = []
 output application/java
 ---     
 if (payload.success contains true and payload.accepted contains true)
 {    
     if (lnc_id contains vars.payload_json.data.LNC_ID)
         {
             lnc_id + lnc_id contains vars.payload_json.data.LNC_ID
         }
 }
```

I'm writing and Api with Mulesoft and I need an IF inside another IF, the language is Datawave 2.0.

The error is:

> "Invalid input "f ", expected Namespace "

Answer (score 1):

You script has several issues:

- {} denotes an object, you need to
  use attributes inside an object instead of expressions.
- Each if has to have an else clause.
- lnc_id will
  not preserve values between executions, so it will always start as an
  empty array (this might be expected but I wanted to clarify it just in case).

This is a simpler example of how to nest if...else

```
 var list = []
 var success = true
 output application/java
 ---     
 if (success == true )
    if (3 > 2)
            ( list + "something")
     else null
 else null
```